# Loading Byte data from database file

Tags: vb.net

I am using following code to get data from database and load to picture box

```
Dim vrPicFromDB = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(DsPic.tblPicTest.Item("Picture"))
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(vrPicFromDB)
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

It gives error on DsPic.tblPicTest.Item("Picture")) portion of the statement.
I also tried

```
CByte(DsPic.tblPicTest.Item("Picture")))
```

but it gives the same error.

Please advise how to fix it.
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: What is the specific error that you are getting. Also what type of column is "Picture" in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the "Picture" column is an Image column in the database, your line to load the vrPicFromDB byte array will look something like this:

```
        Dim vrPicFromDB As Byte()
    vrPicFromDB = CType(DsPic.tblPicTest.Rows(0).Item("Picture"), Byte())
```

That line assume you have loaded at least 1 row of data.